AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
Good time of the day, all.
Can't get rid of this error message. Although the function is working, but I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'" error message.
Code:
class CopyNormals(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Transfer seams normals from source mesh"""
bl_idname = "object.copynormals"
bl_label = "Copy Seams Normals"

def execute(self, context):
    targetMesh = bpy.context.active_object
    sourceMesh = next(o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o != targetMesh) 

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DATA_TRANSFER')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].use_loop_data = True
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].data_types_loops = {'CUSTOM_NORMAL'}
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].use_max_distance = True
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].max_distance = 0.01
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].object = sourceMesh
 #  bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="DataTransfer")

    print("Seams Normals Has Been Copied.")

    return {'FINISHED'}

If I deleting that function error message dissapears.
I've looked though similar threads, but can't figure out how to solve it in my case. I need some advice please.
Full error log is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\power_sequencer\operators\speed_remove_effect.py", line 33, in poll
return context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.type == "META"
11
47
^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\power_sequencer\operators\make_hold_frame.py", line 42, in poll
return context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.type in SequenceTypes.VIDEO
11
47
^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

Why does SequenceTypes.VIDEO even here?
Full code:

import bpy
import os
import struct
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
path = "C:/"
def main(context):
global path
basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
obj = bpy.context.object
obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)
triangulateDetected = None

for modifier in obj.modifiers:

    if modifier.type == "TRIANGULATE":
        print ("Modifier TRIANGULATE was found")
        triangulateDetected = True
            

    else:
        print ("Modifier TRIANGULATE not found")
        triangulateDetected = False
            

if triangulateDetected:
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Triangulate"].keep_custom_normals = True   
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path + name + ".fbx", use_selection=True, use_mesh_modifiers=True, mesh_smooth_type='FACE', axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Triangulate")
    print("Triangulated mesh has been written:", fn)

else:
    print ("Modifier TRIANGULATE not found")
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Triangulate"].keep_custom_normals = True
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path + name + ".fbx", use_selection=True, use_mesh_modifiers=True, mesh_smooth_type='FACE', axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Triangulate")
    print("Triangulated mesh has been written:", fn)
for obj in selection:

    obj.data.materials.clear()

    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path + name + "_quad.fbx", use_selection=True, use_mesh_modifiers=True, mesh_smooth_type='FACE', axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')

    print("Quad mesh has been written:", fn)    

    obj.select_set(False)

    view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)

class SaveTrisAndQuad(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Export quad and triangulated meshes, apply transforms and delete materials"""
bl_idname = "object.savetrisandquad"
bl_label = "Save tiangulated and Quad mesh"
dirpath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')
def execute(self, context):
    main(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}

class SelectDirExample(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Select output directory"""
bl_idname = "object.selectdir"
bl_label = "Select Dir"
bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
global path


# Define this to tell 'fileselect_add' that we want a directoy
directory: StringProperty(
    name="dirpath",
    description="Where I will save my stuff",
    subtype='DIR_PATH'
    )

# Filters folders
filter_folder: BoolProperty(
    default=True,
    options={"HIDDEN"}
    )

def execute(self, context):
    global path

    print("Selected dir: '" + self.directory + "'")
    path =  self.directory
    context.area.tag_redraw()

    return {'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):

    context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
    # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input

    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

class CopyNormals(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Transfer seams normals from source mesh"""
bl_idname = "object.copynormals"
bl_label = "Copy Seams Normals"
def execute(self, context):
    targetMesh = bpy.context.active_object
    sourceMesh = next(o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o != targetMesh) 

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DATA_TRANSFER')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].use_loop_data = True
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].data_types_loops = {'CUSTOM_NORMAL'}
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].use_max_distance = True
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].max_distance = 0.01
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"].object = sourceMesh
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="DataTransfer")

    print("Seams Normals Has Been Copied.")

    return {'FINISHED'}

Creating Panel ======================================
class RedNeckPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_label = "RedNeck Tools"
bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_redneck"
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'UI'
bl_category = "RedNeck"
global path
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    obj = context.object
    layout.label(text="FBX Mesh Exporter")
    row = layout.row()
    row.scale_y = 3.0        
    row.operator(SelectDirExample.bl_idname, text="Output Directory", icon='FILE_FOLDER')

    row = layout.row()
    row.scale_y = 3.0  
    row.operator(SaveTrisAndQuad.bl_idname, text="Export Mesh", icon='EXPORT')


    layout.label(text="Output Directory: " + "<" + path + ">")
    row = layout.row()        

Creating Panel ======================================
_classes = [
SaveTrisAndQuad,
RedNeckPanel,
SelectDirExample,
CopyNormals
]
def register():
for cls in _classes:
register_class(cls)
def unregister():
for cls in _classes:
unregister_class(cls)
if name == "main":
register()

Thanks.

It just means that you have no active video strip selected https://i.sstatic.net/BOxy0Cqz.png. Your have another script (from Power Sequencer addon) that you did not show in this question that is being executed with the line context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip.type and since context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip is None you get this error. Just disable that addon if you don't need it.

There's literally nothing about Power Sequencer in my script and I can't figure out why it goes there. Script have nothing to do with Power Sequencer. If I deleting that function I posted above error message disappears.

I tried with Power Sequencer enabled but can't reproduce your problem. It's probably because something is updating the Power Sequencer like some depsgraph or Application Handler callback triggered. I would consider that a bug in Power Sequencer. You should probably report it to them. Why not disable Power Sequencer for now? Or try uninstalling it and then installing again.

This error is not coming from your script at all. It’s coming from the Power Sequencer addon, as stated in the source file location in the traceback. If your script is failing, it is either not causing an exception, or you’ve copied the wrong one from the log.

Yeah, I see it, but I can't figure out why it goes there. Script have nothing to do with Sequencer.

@DmitryStogov “This error is not coming from your script at all,” means, this error is NOT coming from your script AT ALL. The same error will appear wether you use your script or not, and will not appear if you disable PowerSequencer.
